# How can I get the Doctrine entity metadata before compiling Symfony container?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In one Symfony bundle I define a compiler pass to preprocess some configuration. Part of that config is based on Doctrine entities, so I need to get the full metadata information for all application entities.

The compiler pass is executed very late (`PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_REMOVING`). I'm using `$container->get('doctrine')` like this to get the entity metadata:

```
$em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManagerForClass($entityClass);
$entityMetadata = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($entityClass);
```

However, this is causing random failures for some users because of the use of the `doctrine` service during the Symfony container compilation.

Comment: What do you mean by random failures? Do the failures occur if you run the CompilerPass earlier?

Comment: It's bad idea, because entities metadata can be modified after container compilation (dynamic registration loadClassMetadata listeners for example).

Comment: @ArturVesker I will gladly ignore the edge case of the loadClassMetadata listeners. I can't understand why I cannot get the entity metadata before running the application. All the information is there and nothing changes :(

Comment: @chalasr most of the times it works great ... but some users register other bundles related to Doctrine and this makes the `doctrine` service to not be available in the container during compilation. It happens the same with the `twig` service: you can't use it because it's "synthetic" during compilation.

Comment: Try TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING instead of TYPE_BEFORE_REMOVING

Comment: @JavierEguiluz Are you able to change the pass ordering? `TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING` should effectively avoid the behavior instability.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to change your entities addressing. Mainly - create your models with interfaces and make entities implementing them.

Using `resolve_target_entities` Doctrine will "convert" them to the particular classes.

An example code is here: https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/DoctrineTargetEntitiesResolverPass.php

Just make sure your bundle is registered *before* `DoctrineBundle` is registered.

Then - in your whole app - instead of `AppBundle::Entity` addressing, use FQDN of interface bound to an entity earlier.

I've experimented a bit with compilers and services and it's a **very bad idea** to base on cross-bundle services under compiling container process... Why? It's not reliable - sometimes it will work as you want, sometimes it will fail as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments and ideas. I post an answer to explain how I solved this problem.

Trying to use the Doctrine service in a compiler pass was creating more and more problems for our users (and it was creating other minor issues with other services such as Twig). So this was definitely a bad solution for our needs.

So at the end I decided to change everything. We no longer use a compiler pass to process the configuration and instead we use a regular PHP class called during runtime.

In the dev environment, the configuration is processed for each request. It's a bit slower than before, but we prevent any caching issue. In the prod environment we use Doctrine Cache to process the configuration once. Besides, we've create a cache warmer to create the cached configuration before the first request hits the application.